# Do block resolve types

Tags: haskell, scotty

I just start coding in Haskell recently and I start getting use of **do block**. I'm coming from Scala world, and after read a book and some blogs I see that **do block** was the inspiration of our from comprehension. But still I´m struggling with the arguments that pass in every function as input -> output

Here in my code I'm using scotty http server library to get a request and I'm trying to persist that request in mySQL.

But in this line where I try top get the value from the Maybe to send to the another function to be persisted

> ```
> user <- (fmap (\user -> insertUser user) maybeUser)
> ```

It never compile since the function does not return the expected type

> ActionT Text IO (Maybe User)

but

> IO User

Here my hole program

```
createUser :: ActionM ()
createUser =  do maybeUser <- getUserParam
                          -- Persist the user
                          _ <- persistUser
                          json maybeUser

getUserParam :: ActionT Text IO (Maybe User)
getUserParam = do requestBody <- body
                  return (decode requestBody)

persistUser :: Maybe User -> ActionT Text IO (Maybe User)
persistUser _maybeUser = let maybeUser = _maybeUser in do
                           user <- maybeUser
                           user <- (fmap (\user -> insertUser user) maybeUser)
                           return maybeUser

insertUser :: User -> IO User
insertUser _user = let user = _user in do
    conn <- createConnection
    status <- execute conn insertUserQuery [MySQLInt32 (intToInt32 $ getUserId user), MySQLText "hello_haskell_world"]
    return user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the following function:

```
persistUser :: Maybe User -> ActionT Text IO (Maybe User)
```

A value of type `Maybe User` is passed as an argument, and we need this user to be inserted into database. In order to do that, we can use [`(<$>)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E) (or `fmap`) function as:

```
insertUser <$> maybeUser
```

The resulting type is: `Maybe (IO User)`. Now we need to [lift](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers#Lifting) this type to `ActionT Text IO (Maybe User)` somehow.

`Web.Scotty.Trans` has a [liftAndCatchIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.2/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html#v:liftAndCatchIO) function (also available in `Web.Scotty` module), which mostly does what we need, but it accepts `IO a` as an argument, so we need to "swap" `Maybe` and `IO`. Let's [find](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe%20%28IO%20a%29%20-%3E%20IO%20%28Maybe%20a%29) a function for this. So [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence) does what we need.

As a result, we have the following implementation of `persistUser` function:

```
persistUser maybeUser =
    liftAndCatchIO $ sequence $ insertUser <$> maybeUser
```

Comment: Thanks great explanation and implementation